# How to get App_StoreKey.pfx file for Xamarin UWP application?

Tags: xamarin, azure-devops, uwp, windows-store, pfx

Before in Visual Studio 2019, when I associate my app with the Microsoft Store, it would automatically generate an App_StoreKey.pfx file for my application, however now it just generates a Package.StoreAssociation.xml file. I need the App_Store.pfx file for use in my Azure Devops pipeline, but I do not know how to get it.

My question is what are the steps to get the `App_StoreKey.pfx` file which would be from a trusted CA (Windows Store)? I know it is possible because I have done it before but I cannot seem to figure it out anymore.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48509114/how-to-create-a-working-trusted-and-or-self-signed-certificate-for-a-windows-10

Comment: @Ax1le looked through and still could not get the steps I need to achieve what I want. Any thoughts on what specific parts I should look at?